# alpaca data not streaming

Tags: terminal, windows-10, data-stream, wscat

I am trying to stream data by using an Alpaca paper trading account on a Windows 10 terminal, but instead of streaming data it returns empty. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

note: I have installed wscat by typing `npm install -g wscat` and i have also downloaded `node.js`

First I type:

`wscat -c wss://paper-api.alpaca.markets/stream`

The terminal respondes with:

*Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)*

I then follow up with:

`{"action": "authenticate","data": {"key_id": "my_key_id", "secret_key": "my_secret_key"}}`

The terminal responds with:

*{"stream":"authorization","data":{"action":"authenticate","status":"authorized"}}*

Finally I type:

`{"action": "listen", "data": {"streams": ["T.SPY"]}}`

The terminal responds with:

*{"stream":"listening","data":{"streams":[]}}*

I want it to reply with streaming data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work for me was because I was using a paper trading account instead of a live trading account. If you want to stream on a paper trading account follow these steps:

Firstly download `node.js` on the internet.

After you have downloaded `node.js` open up your terminal and type:

`npm install -g wscat`

When `wscat` has been installed type:

`wscat -c wss://stream.data.alpaca.markets/v2/iex`

The terminal will respond with:

`[{"T":"success","msg":"connected"}]`

Then you type:

`{"action": "auth", "key": "your_key", "secret": "your_secret_key"}`

The terminal will respond with:

`[{"T":"success","msg":"authenticated"}]`

Lastly you type:

`{"action":"subscribe","quotes":["SPY"]}`

Now you should be getting streamed data from a paper trading account on your terminal.